# Custom computer names - MDT

Tags: sccm, mdt, name

Ive recently set up automated MDT service (skipped all the skippable), but Im having issues with the computer name.

Is there a way how to achieve systematized Computer names in automated MDT deployment? For Example MDT1, MD2, MD3 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

I found a script at [Windwos Script Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SCCM-MDT-Computer-Auto-7969a373) and changed all the neccesary details. At first had some issues with name lenghts and what no but at the end managed it to work.

Anyhow before you use it dont assign computers identical names or you wont be able to use the pc if its in AD and local admin is disabled.